# Not getting values using subscribe

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I am trying to get data from subscribe and it seems to go past that step. I would like to know what am I doing here ?

```
this.store.dispatch(new PrimaryActions.CreateData(this.Id)).subscribe(
  result => {
    console.log('Response',result); // not getting the data
    this.saved.emit(result);
    this.onDialogClose();
  });

@Action(PrimaryActions.CreateData)
    createData(context: StateContext<PrimaryStateModel>, action: PrimaryActions.CreateData) {
    return this.dataService.createData(action.id).pipe(
        tap((result: Modal) => {
            console.log('response', result); // getting the right data here
            this.store.dispatch(new PrimaryActions.LoadData());
        })
    );
    }
```

Comment: Unless Im mistaken, your using ngxs. The dispatch method of the store of ngxs returns an observable of `void`, so you can't extract a value from it. In the [documentation](https://www.ngxs.io/concepts/store#dispatching-actions) you can find an example of how to achieve that using a selector.

Comment: Why not you use rxjs?

Answer (score 0):

You'll never get the value from by dispatching an action. The flow of NgRx it's something like:

- dispatch your action using `dispatch`
- have a reducer that listen to that action and update your state
- if you have some side effects (like calling an api) you'll use effects for dispatching actions after you get the response from the api.
  But the main idea is to `dispatch` an action and then react to that action through a `reducer`.
  To get the data from your store you'll need a `selector`.

You can see more basic examples here: https://ngrx.io/guide/store/walkthrough